# Reading picture from byte array

Tags: java, image, arrays, inputstream

I'm writing a Java applet that need to read some XML and image files inside a ZIP file. The Zip file will be download through HTTP and the applet is unsigned, so I need to use `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream` to manipulated the data. There's a problem when I'm trying to read a PNG file inside the Zip file.

The steps I handle the Zip file:

1. Download the Zip through Http

   ```java
   URL resourceURL = new URL(source);
   HttpURLConnection httpConnection= (HttpURLConnection) resourceURL.openConnection();
   httpConnection.connect();
   InputStream resourceFileIn = httpConnection.getInputStream();
   ```
2. Use ZipInputStream to hold the data downloaded

   ```java
   ZipInputStream resourceZipIn = new ZipInputStream(resourceFileIn);
   ```
3. Iterate through every ZipEntry and extract the corresponding byte array

   ```java
   ArrayList<ExtractedEntry> extractedList = new ArrayList<ExtractedEntry>();
   ZipEntry currentEntry;
   while ((currentEntry = resourceZipIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {
       byte[] byteHolder = new byte[(int) currentEntry.getSize()];
       resourceZipIn.read(byteHolder, 0, byteHolder.length);
       extractedList.add(new ExtractedEntry(currentEntry.getName(), byteHolder));
   }
   ```

   remarks: every ZipEntry extracted is hold by the following class

   ```java
   public class ExtractedEntry {
       private String name;
       private byte[] byteArray;

       public ExtractedEntry(String name, byte[] byteArray) {
           super();
           this.name = name;
           this.byteArray = byteArray;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public byte[] getByteArray() {
           return byteArray;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Find the file I want to read from in the extracted list

   ```java
   ExtractedEntry bgEntry = null;
   for (int j = 0; j < extractedList.size() && bgEntry == null; j++) {
       if (extractedList.get(j).getName().equals("background.png")) {
           bgEntry = extractedList.get(j);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Perform specific action according to need

   ```java
   InputStream mapBgIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bgEntry.getByteArray());
   BufferedImage bgEntry = ImageIO.read(bgIn);
   ```

---

I list out only the action of reading the PNG file as that is where I encounter the problem. When I try to read the image in the way mentioned above, I always receive the following error at the last line of step 5.

```java
javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.quadd.soft.game.wtd.lib.resource.ResourceManager.loadHttpZipRes(ResourceManager.java:685)
Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Unknown row filter type (= 7)!
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodePass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodeImage(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more
```

---

However, if I read the image in the following way starting from step 3, there's no problem.

```java
ZipInputStream resourceZipIn = new ZipInputStream(resourceFileIn);
ZipEntry testEntry;
while ((testEntry = resourceZipIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if (testEntry.getName().equals("background.png")) {
        BufferedImage bgEntry = ImageIO.read(resourceZipIn);
    }
}
```

---

Therefore, I guess that there's some problem with my code at extracting the bytes from `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream` and put it back for reading the image. But I'm quite new to manipulating stream so I just couldn't figure out what exactly is the problem. I would like to ask if anyone could point out what mistake I've made in the code which cause the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` method does not guarantee that it fills the byte array; it reads only a small block and returns the number of bytes that it read. You need a loop, or use a helper class that does fill the array.

For example

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(resourceZipIn);
in.readFully(byteHolder);
in.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solve the problem immediately.

I just have another question regarding the 'read' method. Is that the 'read' method of InputStream and all subclass share the same property that they don't guarantee fills the byte array?

Comment: Not all subclasses: [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) for example guarantees that it will read as much as possible. Other input streams, like `FileInputStream` or `SocketInputStream`, can't make such guarantees without sacrificing efficiency.