# Android as client and PC as server. Socket program to transfer image from phone to PC

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, javax.imageio

So I have been trying to transfer an image from android to pc via socket program. but the transfer is ambiguous as sometimes the server crashes or sometimes I'm not able to receive the complete image.

**Server**

```
while (true) {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5001);
            System.out.println("Server is running at port 5001");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

            System.out.println("Reading: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

            byte[] sizeAr = new byte[4];
            inputStream.read(sizeAr);
            int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeAr).asIntBuffer().get();

            byte[] imageAr = new byte[size];
            System.out.println(imageAr);
            inputStream.read(imageAr);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageAr));

            System.out.println("Received " + image.getHeight() + "x" + image.getWidth() + ": " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            name = "test" + count + ".png";
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(name));
            count++;
            //new CopyCut(name);
            serverSocket.close();}
```

There I am receiving the image from the following client:

**Client**

```
public void Client(Bitmap bitmap,Context context){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
    //byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
    try {
            if(ip.isEmpty()){
                ipSetting(context);
            }
        s = new Socket(ip, 5001);
        OutputStream outputStream = s.getOutputStream();
        byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(baos.size()).array();
        outputStream.write(size);
        outputStream.write(baos.toByteArray());
        outputStream.flush();
        s.close();

    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

what is it wrong I'm doing that server crashes or image is partially received.
when the server crashes following error comes.

**Error**

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1345)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1614)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)
at ServerImage.run(ServerImage.java:33)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Unknown row filter type (= 128)!
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodePass(PNGImageReader.java:1143)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodeImage(PNGImageReader.java:1223)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1338)
... 5 more
```

if possible help me with correct code.

Comment: read() does not guarantee it fills the byte array. Please see the accepted answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831871/reading-picture-from-byte-array)

Comment: In addition to using `DataInputStream` to read the size, I like to point out that using `ImageIO` here is just a waste of time and space (RAM). Instead, just copy the bytes from the socket input stream to the output file on the server. The data is already in the PNG file format.